# Plugin routing casing: camel, lower, Pascal

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, controller, uppercase

Recently got tripped up with plugin routing due to casing.

It seems when you're in the control panel, your "plugin handle" is lower-cased in routes, though both seem to work: `/cp/settings/plugins/myplugin` (/cp/settings/plugins/myPlugin` also works)

However, when using an controller action, it seems like it must be camel cased (`/actions/myPlugin/foo`).

Seems inconsistent, unless I'm missing some reasoning.

The [docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing) say `[PluginHandle]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]`, but it seems like it's actually `[pluginHandle]/[controllerName]/[actionName]` as the example shows (`cocktailRecipes/ingredients/saveIngredient`).

Answer (score 3):

This is the general rule of thumb...

- **Lower (myplugin)** - When creating links for the browser to follow ("href" & "src")
- **Camel (myPlugin)** - When creating a path for PHP to interpret (like calling an action)
- **Pascal (MyPlugin)** - Almost never. Only for naming plugin components. (ie: MyPluginService)

Here's the logic behind lower vs. camel... If it's an "href" or "src" for your browser to follow, you're basically referring to the **folder name** which contains your plugin. If it's a reference for PHP to interpret, that information is used to trigger a part of your plugin by **class name**.

In the case of a controller action (`/actions/myPlugin/foo`), that path **starts** as a normal browser path, until `actions` gets interpreted by your root `index.php` file. Once the index file parses out the [actionTrigger](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#actionTrigger), the rest of the path is handled via PHP.

Comment: That makes sense.
It still feels a little funny to me that it is case insensitive one way (template/cp routing) and not the other way (controller action).

Comment: I agree, it took me a little while to wrap my head around. Ultimately, the case-insensitivity is just due to server behavior... nothing that Craft can really even do about it. Despite the case-insensitivity, I use lowercase because you're referring to the folder itself (which is lowercase).